# How to double the size of a 2D array with char elements inside

Tags: c

So I want to make a 2D array like this:
`XX??XX??`
`XX??XX??`
`??XX??XX`
`??XX??XX`
`XX??XX??`
`XX??XX??`

into this:
`XXXX????XXXX????`
`XXXX????XXXX????`
`XXXX????XXXX????`
`XXXX????XXXX????`
`????XXXX????XXXX`
`????XXXX????XXXX`
`????XXXX????XXXX`
`????XXXX????XXXX`
`XXXX????XXXX????`
`XXXX????XXXX????`
`XXXX????XXXX????`
`XXXX????XXXX????`

This is what I have so far:

```
void DoubleUP(char Box1[6][8], char Box2[12][16]){
int i,j,r,c;
r=0;
c=0;


for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){

        if(Box1[i][j]== 'X'){
            Box2[r][c]='X';
            Box2[r][c+1] ='X';
            Box2[r+1][c] ='X';
            Box2[r+1][c+1] ='X';
            c+=2;
        }
        else{
            Box2[r][c]='?';
            Box2[r][c+1] ='?';
            Box2[r+1][c] ='?';
            Box2[r+1][c+1] ='?';
            c+=2;
        }


    }
    r+=2;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Or if there is an easier way to make Box1 go into Box2 with double the scale, that would help too. Thanks.

Comment: allocate and then reallocate using the aptly named `realloc` function. Note that arrays decay into pointers when passed to functions, too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the loop：

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        Box2[i][j] = Box1[i / 2][j / 2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've noticed that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        Box2[2*i][2*j]=Box1[i][j];
        Box2[2*i][(2*j)+1]=Box1[i][j];
        Box2[(2*i)+1][2*j]=Box1[i][j];
        Box2[(2*i)+1][(2*j)+1]=Box1[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten and generalize the code a bit, but you got the right idea on how to do it.

```
void DoubleUP(char Box1[6][8], char Box2[12][16]){
int i,j,r,c;

    for (i=0, r=0; i<6; i++, r+=2) {
        for (j=0, c=0; j<8; j++, c+=2) {

            Box2[r][c]   = Box1[i][j];
            Box2[r][c+1] = Box1[i][j];
            Box2[r+1][c]  =Box1[i][j];
            Box2[r+1][c+1]=Box1[i][j];
        }
    }   
}
```